# Can't return data from Content Picker in Umbraco 7.6.4

Tags: razor, umbraco

I am currently trying to output data from the new Multinode Treepicker in Umbraco 7.6.4 here is my current setup and code:

**Doctype**

[image: Screenshot of Doctype]

**Content Node with 'Page' Doctype**
[image: Screenshot of content node]

Code to output the names of the selected nodes:

```
@{
    IPublishedContent typedContentPicker = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IPublishedContent>("sections");
    if (typedContentPicker != null)
    {
        <p>@typedContentPicker.Name</p>                                                
    } 
}
```

This I took from the official [Umbraco Documentation](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/Content-Picker2) and adapted it to my project. This code is in a template with the 'page' doctype.

Currently the above code does not output anything to my page, I am expecting to see a list of nodes displayed on the page, can anyone see what the issue is or where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dumb moment, I was looking at the documentation for a content picker and not a multi-node tree picker!

Correct code is:

```
@{
var typedMultiNodeTreePicker = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("sections");
    foreach (var item in typedMultiNodeTreePicker)
    {
        <p>@item.Name</p>
    }
}
```